# Negative Numbers and Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorem

Tags: computability, turing-machines, incompleteness

I was examining **Q** (Robinson Arithmetic) when it occurred to me that **Q** contains no statements about the negative numbers or subtraction. No resource that I’ve been able to find has discussed Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems for theories of arithmetic for $\mathbb Z$.

My question is: Is there a reason for this widespread omission?

There seems to be an obvious way to extend axiomatic sets like **Q** and **PA** to deal with negative numbers. There also seems like there is an easy way to extend Gödel’s Second Incompleteness Theorem to arithmetic in $\mathbb Z$. Is there a reason why this doesn’t seem to be done, or even noted, in most sources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that the main reason is that the extension from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is pretty trivial, and $\mathbb{N}$ is a more "limited" system, so there is a perceived elegance in proving the theorem in the most limited context, so that it has the broadest applicability.

One extension from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ goes through Lagrange's four square lemma: every natural number is the sum of four squares of integers.  So, if we can only quantify over $\mathbb{Z}$, we can fake quantifying over $\mathbb{N}$:
$$
(\exists n)[(\exists a,b,c,d)[a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = n] \land \ldots ]
$$
Hence the theory of $(\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$ interprets the theory of $(\mathbb{N},+,\times)$.   Similarly, axiomatic theories of $\mathbb{Z}$ will interpret axiomatic theories of $\mathbb{N}$, allowing the incompleteness theorem to transfer.

Comment: +1. Note to the OP: Lagrange's four square lemma was what I was referencing when I said that $\mathbb{N}$ is definable in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, and helps me better understand what @NoahSchweber meant. If I want to create an axiomatic system for $(\mathbb Z,+,\times)$ that’s as strong as **Q**, is there a systematic way I can modify the ones on Wikipedia, going in the opposite direction of what you describe? It seems like minor modification to the axioms on Wikipedia for **Q** would do the trick, but I worry that adding something like $\varphi(x)\lor \varphi(-x)\lor (x = 0)$ might make the system stronger than I had intended.

Comment: You could probably find a modified version of Q that would work. I think that the way most people would accommodate Z is to start with a theory of natural numbers and then use a definitional extension to create Z. For example an integer can be defined as a pair of natural numbers $(a,b)$, which is intended to represent $b-a$. This avoids having to restate the induction axioms, which are easier to state for naturals.

Answer (score 6):

Godel's theorems do indeed still hold for $\mathbb{Z}$. The easiest one to port over is the "strong first theorem," that no recursively axiomatizable extension of $B$ is complete for some appropriate theory $B$ which is true of $(\mathbb{Z};+,\times, S)$. This (once an appropriate $B$ has been defined) is just a corollary of the usual Godel's theorem since the natural numbers are definable in $\mathbb{Z}$. This means that given any set of sentences $T$ about $\mathbb{Z}$ we get a corresponding set $T_\mathbb{N}$ of "sentences about $\mathbb{N}$ which $T$ proves" - namely, fixing a formula $\varphi$ defining $\mathbb{N}$, $T_\mathbb{N}$ is the set of sentences $\psi$ such that $T\vdash \psi^\varphi$ (where "$\psi^\varphi$" is the **relativization** of $\psi$ to the set defined by $\varphi$; just change "$\exists x(...)$" to "$\exists x(\varphi(x)\wedge...)$" and change "$\forall x(...)$" to "$\forall x(\varphi(x)\implies ...)$"). The key point is that $T_\mathbb{N}$ is recursively axiomatizable since $T$ is, and will be sufficiently strong as long as $B$ is.

OK, what should our $B$ be? Well, we can just take $B=Q^\varphi$, the set of relativizations-to-$\varphi$ of axioms in Robinson arithmetic; then for any $T\supseteq B$ we'll have $T_\mathbb{N}\supseteq Q$. Note that at no point do we have to "redo" the usual proof of Godel's theorem.

As to why everything is presented over $\mathbb{N}$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}$, I don't know any good reason for that; I think it's probably just convention. (Although maybe Diophantine equations are nicer than integral equations, sometimes?)

Comment: Diophantine equations are indeterminate algebraic equations where the unknowns are integers; integral equations are equations in which the unknown function appears under an integral sign. Which is nicer depends on the equations.

Comment: One interesting theorem that leverages negative numbers is that every r.e. set is the intersection of the natural numbers with the range of a multivariate integer polynomial, where the domain of the variables is the set of integers.  So the outputs that are nonnegative form the r.e. set, while the negative outputs are ignored.

Comment: ... Similar tricks are used in the proof of Matiyasevich's theorem: we can force something to be solvable, or not solvable, by forcing the root to be nonnegative or negative, since our solutions can only be nonnegative.